# Let X be normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$, find the CDF and density of $Y = \Phi(X)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Define $\Phi(x)$ as:
>   $$
> \Phi(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\right) dt
> $$
>   and let the random variable $Y$ be defined as $\Phi(X)$ where $X$ is a standard normal variable (i.e. with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$).
>
> What is the CDF and density of $Y$?

#### Progress

My thoughts are that I can substitute $Y$ into the CDF given, which is $\Phi (x) = \text{ CDF of }X = P(X < x)$, thus getting $P(\Phi(x) < y)$. I then figured that I can inverse both sides to get $P(X < \Phi^{-1}(y))$. At this point, I'm unclear how to proceed, as in I don't know how to express the CDF.

Also, I was told to find the density which I believe I simply have to differentiate the function, but I'm also unclear on how to differentiate since there seems to be 3 different variables x, y and t and I'm not sure which to eliminate or replace...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant $\infty$ to be $-\infty$, so I edited it appropriately.

Comment: Anyway, any thoughts on the question?

Comment: hi, yes thank you for editing it for me. it's my first time using stackexchange, i was trying to figure out how to properly format the equation. My thoughts are that I can substitute Y into the CDF given, which is Φ(x) = CDF of X = P(X < x), thus getting P(Φ(x) < y). I then figured that I can inverse both sides to get P(X < $Φ^{-1}$(y)). At this point, I'm unclear how to proceed, as in I don't know how to express the CDF.

Comment: Also, I was told to find the density which I believe I simply have to differentiate the function, but I'm also unclear on how to differentiate since there seems to be 3 different variables x, y and t and I'm not sure which to eliminate or replace...

Comment: $X$ follows the standard normal distribution, so $\mathbb{P}\left(X \leq x\right) = \Phi(x)$. Thus, $\mathbb{P}\left(X \leq \Phi^{-1}(y)\right) = \Phi\left(\Phi^{-1}(y)\right)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm vaguely aware that based on P(X < $Φ^{-1}$(y)) I can simply plug in $Φ^{-1}$(y) into Φ(x) and get y, but still unclear on how to express the CDF... do I replace the x in the upper limit with y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following observations

1. $Y$ takes values in $[0,1]$,
2. $Φ(\cdot)$ is strictly monotone increasing and therefore invertible. Let $Φ^{-1}$ denote it's inverse,

the CDF $F_Y(y)$ of $Y$ is given by $$F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(Φ
(X)\le y)=P(X\le Φ^{-1}(y))=Φ(Φ^{-1}(y))=y$$ for $y\in[0,1]$. Thus $$f_Y(y)=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}F_Y(y)=(y)'=1$$ for $y \in [0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere, which means that $Y$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. In sum $$F_Y(y)=\begin{cases}0, &y<0\\\frac{y-0}{1-0}=y, & 0\le y\le 1\\1, & y>1 \end{cases}$$ and $$f_Y(y)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{1-0}=1, & 0\le y\le 1\\0, & \text{ else } \end{cases}$$

---

The above definition of $Y$ is related to the concept of [inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Comment: wait, so CDF of Y is simply y?

Comment: Yes, but for $y$ in $[0,1]$. Y has the uniform distribution in $[0,1]$

Comment: Sorry, just to be 100% clear: I simply state that the CDF of Y, FY(y), is y? I do not have to state any parts of the original function?

Comment: @tpayne - Well, of course, $F_{Y}(y) = y$ for $y \in [0, 1]$. The reason is that $\Phi(\cdot) \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: okay, thank you so much for your help, you guys are incredible and i love this forum!

Comment: You are welcome, thanks for your love :)!

Comment: one more question: how do i then find the CDF and density of Z = $Φ(X)^2$ ? I tried square-rooting both sides, and I arrived at P(-z < Φ(x) < z). Is that right?

Comment: You do not need $X$. $Z=Y^2$ and you have $Y$ already....

Comment: So I find $P(-\sqrt{z} < Y < \sqrt{z})$?

Comment: Yes, and take cases for z<0, z in [0,1] and z>1

Comment: so is the following right: $F_Y$ = $-\sqrt{z}$ for z<0, $F_y$ = $\sqrt{z}$ for z in [0,1], and 1 for z>1?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $Y$ is a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$